# Barplot: to show NULL data

Tags: r, bar-chart

I work on R.
I have several barplot to produce and I would like to have the same x-axis (xlim, xaxp) for all of them.
The only problem is that because it is a barplot, the data that don´t exist in my file will not appear. For example, I want to have the x-axis from 0 to 64, but for some of my barplot, max(x-axis) is not 64 but less than this.

How can I do to have for all of the barplot an axis going from 0 to 64 with few labels on it? I would love to have the empty values there...

Here is an example:

```
Stops   Month   Hoursdecimal
2   May 41
3   May 16
4   May 16
5   May 40
55  June    64
65  June    39
1   July    15
2   July    14
3   August  39
5   August  15
6   August  14
7   August  40
15  August  43
3   September   40
4   September   14
5   September   14
6   September   42
74  June    40
75  June    14
76  June    13
78  June    16
4   July    28
```

Here is the script I have for now:

```
data2 <- read.csv("C:/Users/Florent/Desktop/R/Overview2014/time.csv", header = TRUE, sep=";", dec=",")
place1<-data2[data2$place=="Helsinki",]
helsinki$Hoursdecimal<-as.factor(helsinki$Hoursdecimal)
g2<- table(helsinki$Hoursdecimal)
g2<-prop.table(g2) 
g2<-g2*100
barplot(g2)
barplot(g2, axe=F, space=c(0.2), las=1, col=c("gray"), ylim=c(0,35), xlim=c(0,66))
axis(2, line=-0.8, las=1, , yaxp= c(0,35,7))
axis(1, labels=F, tick=T, line=0, tck=0)
title(xlab="Hours spent at sea from previous port", line=2.2, cex.lab=1.3)
title(ylab="% of calls", line=2,  las=2, cex.lab=1.3)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can achieve the desired result by converting your x-axis data to factor with levels that include all the points you want to plot on your x-axis. Would be nice if you show what code you currently use to produce the barplot.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my first message with it. As you can see the Hoursdecimal are already in factor. I have now to do the levels for each value I want a bar (or not if no observation).

Comment: But `g2` is not a factor after you run `table` on it and that is what you are giving to barplot. Read the help page for table to learn how to include zero counts in a table object.